# Ошибка в libxml2

Tags: php, macos, apache2

**Помогите решить проблему.**

После установки `os x el capitan` на свой `mac mini` через `homebrew` поставил `php` и `mysql`. Создал локальный хост, и все работает, но когда делаю `apachectl configtes`t выбрасывает такую ошибку:

> httpd: Syntax error on line 169 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:
>   Cannot load /usr/local/opt/php56/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so into
>   server: dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php56/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so, 10):
>   Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib/libxml2.2.dylib\n
>   Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/php56/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so\n
>   Reason: Incompatible library version: libphp5.so requires version
>   12.0.0 or later, but libxml2.2.dylib provides version 10.0.0

*Уже переустанавливал через homebrew libxml2, облазил весь интернет - ничего не помогает!*

***Ошибку выбрасывает в этой строчке конфига:***

> LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/opt/php56/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so

**Подскажите как это можно исправить!?**

Comment: тебе в голову не приходило перевести сообщение об ошибке? и посмотреть в конфиги? Syntax error on line 169 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf

Comment: @strangeqargo, прочитайте вопрос, я там написал. что много гуглил и искал ответы! Ничего не вышло, потому и сюда написал!

Comment: 1) у тебя синтаксическая ошибка в конфиге апача. Если ты ее не исправишь - весь дальнейший разговор не имеет смысла, ты б хотя бы этот кусок конфига привел в вопросе

Comment: @strangeqargo, вопрос отредактировал и привел кусок кофига !

Answer (score 1):

`google://el capitan libxml2.2.dylib provides version 10.0.0`

первый [результат](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/2508#issuecomment-157324388) в комменте с [гитхаба](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/2508)

> For last couple days I was having the same problem and today I finally
>   solved it. The problem is not in PHP but in Apache 2.4 that is
>   distributed with OSX. The way to solve it is to install apache from
>   brew. What you have to do is simply:

дальше по треду проблема решилась вот [так](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/419#issuecomment-11424345)